# Ubuntu 13.10, brightness settings issue

Tags: brightness

I haven't experienced any issues when 13.10 is installed on my desktop but after installing it on my laptop (Fujitsu LifeBook) the brightness settings seem to default to the dimmest setting and even though I manually slide it to the brightest it will always default each time I reboot.  Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press Ctrl+Alt+t for openeing terminal then use -

```
cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness
```

it will give you the maximum brightness value, to change it for after booting open-

```
sudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

and add the line shown below before exit , look at the screenshort I have attached-

```
echo 0 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

Change 0 to the maximum value as got from previous command output.

as shown here-[image: here changing]

Now just save it and restart. Hope it helped you.